# how to get (txt) file content from FileField?

Tags: python, django, file

I have a problem with opening a text file in django that is stored in my database. I want to access it via FileField of my model... the model looks something like this

```
   class MyModel(models.Model):
      saved_file = FileField()
```

I upload a test file via admin interface, which works ok. In my view I want to access this file. If I open it with standard python open() it works ok...

```
 f = open(path, 'r')
 a = f.readlines()
 return render_to_response('base.html', {'content': a}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this displays lines of the file ok...
according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield one gets a FieldFile proxy when FileField from a model is called, so

```
 f = MyModel.objects.all().get(id=0).saved_file
```

should store FieldFile in f, furthermore documentation states that one opens a file from model by casting .open(mode='rb') on FieldFile, so

```
file = f.open(mode='rb')
```

should work like python .open() as stated in the documentation. So to get lines I do

```
file.readlines()
```

should return me list of lines. What happens is that I get an error saying that .readlines() atribute does not exist. I do not need the file to display it, this is just a way to test if opening a file works, but I need the file content in a variable in my view to further use it in my business logic.
Could anyone suggest a way to get the file content out of a FileField frem a model?

Comment: What's the full traceback of your `AttributeError` ?

Answer (score 8):

Since Django 2.0 `File.open` does return you a file, so suggested way to work is as with context manager:

```py
saved_file = MyModel.objects.all().get(id=0).saved_file
with saved_file.open() as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

---

***Applies to old versions of Django < 2***

`FieldFile.open` opens the file, but doesn't return anything. So in your example `file` is `None`.

You should call readlines on FieldFile. In your example it would be:

```
f = MyModel.objects.all().get(id=0).saved_file
try:
    f.open(mode='rb') 
    lines = f.readlines()
finally:
    f.close()
```

**UPD**: I added `try/finally` block, as the good practice is to always `close` the resource, even if exception happened.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation states that files are opened in 'rb' mode by default, but you would want to open in 'r' to treat the file as a text file:

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
try:
    my_object.saved_file.open('r')
    lines = my_object.saved_file.readlines()
finally:
    my_object.saved_file.close()
```

Even better, you can use a context manager in Django v2.0+

```
my_object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
with my_object.saved_file.open('r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: for the solution without `context manager,` you should use `try: ...open() ... finally: ...close()`

Comment: @mattdedek: you don't need to close the file when using a context manager